# Extracting multiple values from string in python with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have multiple strings which looks like this
`product: green apples price: 2.0 country: france company: somecompany`. Some strings might have fewer fields. For example some are missing company name or country etc. I am trying to extract values only and skip product,price,country,company. I tried to create multiple regexes, which starts from the left side of each string.

```
blah="product: green apples price: 2.0 country: france company: somecompany"

product_reg = re.compile(r'.*?\bproduct\b:(.*).*')
product_reg_strip = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s[a-z]:?')

product_full=re.findall(product_reg, blah)
prod=re.find(product_reg_strip, str(product_full))
print prod

price_reg = re.compile(r'.*?\bprice\b:(.*).*')
price_reg_strip = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s[a-z]:?')

price_full=re.findall(price_reg, blah)
price=re.find(price_reg_strip, str(price_full))
print price
```

But this is not working. What should i do to make this regex more sane?

Comment: Is price the only numerical value in each of the strings?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? In your example, is it `green apples 2.0 france somecompany`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string like that:

```
str = "product: green apples price: 2.0 country: france company: somecompany"
p = re.compile(r'(\w+:)')
res = p.split(str)
print res
for i in range(len(res)):
    if (i%2):
        print res[i],' ==> ',res[i+1]
```

**Output:**

```
['', 'product:', ' green apples ', 'price:', ' 2.0 ', 'country:', ' france ', 'company:', ' somecompany']

product:  ==>   green apples 
price:  ==>   2.0 
country:  ==>   france 
company:  ==>   somecompany
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply a regexp and get named group results.
You also can have or not all the values as you asked, the regexp works fine  in all cases.
Try using this global multiline regexp on regex101.com https://regex101.com/r/iccVUv/1/:

```
^(?:product:(?P<product>.*?))(?:price:(?P<price>.*?))?(?:country:(?P<country>.*?))?(?:company:(?P<company>.*))?$
```

In python you can, for example do this:

```
pattern = '^(?:product:(?P<product>.*?))(?:price:(?P<price>.*?))?(?:country:(?P<country>.*?))?(?:company:(?P<company>.*))?$'
matches = re.search(pattern, 'product: green apples price: 2.0 country: italy company: italian company')
```

Now you can get data simply using:

```
product = matches.group('product')
```

You finally need only to check if the match is satisfacted and trim spaces like:

```
if matches1.group('product') is not None:
  product = matches.group('product').strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are after, but if the things you want to remove are a single word followed by a colon, the regex is pretty easy. Here are a couple of samples.

```
>>> import re
>>> blah="product: green apples price: 2.0 country: france company: somecompany"
>>> re.sub(r'\w+: ?', '', blah)
'green apples 2.0 france somecompany'
>>> re.split(r'\w+: ?', blah)[1:]
['green apples ', '2.0 ', 'france ', 'somecompany']
```